# What is the correct way to format a mac address node for an RFC 4122 Version 1 UUID?

Tags: php, uuid

I'm trying to create a Version 1 UUID based on a mac address as defined on [page 8 of RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) using only PHP. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9321579/594137) on this site recommended [this](https://github.com/fredriklindberg/class.uuid.php) implementation which seems to fit the bill.

I'm testing the usage of this class as follows:

```
<?php
    echo UUID::generate(UUID::UUID_TIME, UUID::FMT_STRING, '000000000000');
?>
```

But I'm getting the following output:

```
6c10f140-28c0-11e2-a210-303030303030
```

My understanding of the standard is that the node (last part) should be the mac address verbatim. Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/fredriklindberg/class.uuid.php/blob/master/class.uuid.php#L250) it seems to use [`ord()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) which looks like it gets the ASCII value of the characters in the string provided to generate the node instead of using the address itself?

Is my understanding of the spec wrong or is the code wrong?

Comment: `substr($node, $i, 1)` makes me cringe :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it in binary form:

```
echo UUID::generate(UUID::UUID_TIME, UUID::FMT_STRING, "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00");
//bfd4d7d0-28c2-11e2-b87b-000000000000
```

This is why the loop goes 6 times, 6 bytes = 48 bits.

Comment: Ah of course. Thank you. And a note to anyone reading this who (like me) their first language is not PHP: remember to use `"..."` because `'...'` won't convert the `\x` references.